# AzureDevops - get-AzureRMroleassignment - [error]Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I created I script in azure-powershell, script containc cmd-let --> `get-azureRMroleAssignment`, and this the main problem, some time ago I had similar problem. I used RunAsAccount, and mentioned RunAsAccount did not have read rights on Azure AD, and this permission is mandatory when using the Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment, since it is required so you can translate the ObjectID stored on role assignments to their corresponding email/userprincipalnames. I granted required permissions in AzureAD, and id solved the problem, and that was when I was using Automation accounts and Runbook. Now I am using Azure devops pipelines, I am connecting to AzureAD, pls have a look at the code below. I am facing the similar issue --> `##[error]Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown.` In Azure AD, App registrations I added Read.DuirectoryData permmision, then tried to consent it in Azure AD --> Enterprise Applications --> permissions, then i click "Grant Admin consent..." button, and got window with my permissions, I confirmed and got next window, confirmed app permissions again and the window froze. I tried to run pipeline again but nothing changed, got the same error message.

```
# Set urls for taking with MS graph
$AdTokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/token"
$Resource = "https://graph.windows.net/"
Write-Debug "AD url is: $AdTokenUrl"

# Set the body of the REST API call 
$Body = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_id = $ClientId
    client_secret = $ClientSecret
    resource = $Resource
}

# Execute REST API call and capture token
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method "Post" -Uri $AdTokenUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $Body
$Token = $Response.access_token

# Connect to AzureAD using -AadAccessToken parameter retrieved from graph API
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $Token -AccountId $ClientId -TenantId $TenantId
```

I checked my Azure Ad --> App registrations --> API permissions and I can see below status:
[image]

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you solve the issue?  If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically address your API problem, but is there any chance you can give the Azure Devops service principle read access to the directory? Then you wouldn't need to separately authenticate or API call. You should then just be able to natively run `Get-AzureRMroleAssignment` in your azure powershell script.

EDIT: It would be worthwhile doing this even for testing purposes. Once functionality is confirmed refactor back to API call if required

Comment: Hi, yes, this is not a problem with API, this is a issue with this cmd-let. As i mentioned, i added required perms on ad for this Azure devops principle, but problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use "Powershell script" task, not "Azure Powershell script" task.
[image], now pipeline works as expected.